# Swap phone number in HTML with URL parameter via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that dynamically changes content on my website based off of a URL parameter. It replaces anything with an ID=test.

I'd like to now try and use the same code, but SWAP a specific phone number on my website. So I'd like to replace any instance of: 888-888-8888 on my website.

I'd love it if someone could show me an example of how to do so that would work with my code below:

my URL format will look like this: test.com/?test=656-566-9696

Thanks so much!

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
{
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
    {
        return sParameterName[1];
    }
}
```

}

```
var test = decodeURIComponent(getUrlParameter('test'));
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = test;
```

Format of numbers in my HTML is:

```
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```

Comment: Why not just change the phone number in the markup itself?

Comment: you're replacing only `+` symbols with space in parameter value at the moment. So, how eventually should look your swapped phone `888-888-8888` ?

Comment: As an aside, be cautious when using innerHTML with user-provided values, as you could expose yourself to [an XSS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). It sounds like you may be using a URL param as the substitute value here so wanted to share.

Comment: Thanks, sorry disregard the + replace. I was using that for content changes. My URL will have: test.com/?test=666-666-6666 then just swap out any instance of the 888-888-8888 in my text when that paramater is appended. The format of my numbers in my text is: tel:1-408-555-5555

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the HTML of the site, you could add a class to all instances of your phone number (e.g. `<span class="phone-number">888-888-8888</span>`). With that in  place, finding all instances of the phone number is easy:

```
// get all spans with phone numbers
var phoneNumbers = document.getElementsByClassName("phone-number");

// loop over and replace their contents with something else
for (i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.length; i++) { 
  phoneNumbers[i].innerHTML = "your new phone";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This could work, but what if my phone number is in the following format?     <a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>

Comment: In that case, you'll want to update both the inner text of the `<a>` element as well as the `href` attribute. You can use the `setAttribute` method to do so: `phoneNumbers[i].setAttribute("href", "tel: your new phone");`